# Python on Windows "Handle Invalid" when redirecting stdout writing to file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, operating-system

A script I am trying to fix uses the following paradigm for redirecting stdout to a file.

```
import os
stdio_file = 'temp.out'
flag = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC
stdio_fp = os.open(stdio_file, flag)
os.dup2(stdio_fp, 1)
print("hello")
```

On Python 2, this works. On Python 3, you get an OSError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("hello")
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I assume there are more preferable methods to routing stdout through a file but I am wondering why this method stopped working in Python 3 and if there is an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @eryksun Your comments are a pretty good answer. Why not make it into one?

Comment: You're right, setting `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO` fixes the problem. However, I am still trying to work through the additional comment in my head. I'm sort of unfamiliar with a lot of the OS stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code such as `os.dup2(stdio_fp, 1)` will work in Python 3.5 and earlier, or in 3.6+ with the environment variable `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO` defined.

The issue is that `print` writes to a `sys.stdout` object that's only meant for console I/O. Specifically, in 3.6+ the raw layer of Python 3's standard output file (i.e. `sys.stdout.buffer.raw`) is an `io._WindowsConsoleIO` instance when stdout is initially a console file<sup>1</sup>. This object caches the initial handle value of the stdout file descriptor<sup>2</sup>. Subsequently, `dup2` closes this handle while re-associating the file descriptor with a duplicate handle for "temp.out". At this point the cached handle is no longer valid. (Really, it shouldn't be caching the handle, since calling `_get_osfhandle` is relatively cheap compared to the cost of console I/O.) However, even if it had a valid handle for "temp.out", `sys.stdout.write` would fail anyway since `_WindowsConsoleIO` uses the console-only function `WriteConsoleW` instead of generic `WriteFile`.

You need to reassign `sys.stdout` instead of bypassing Python's I/O stack with low-level operations such as `dup2`. I know it's not ideal from the Unix developer's point of view. I wish we could re-implement the way Unicode is supported for the Windows console without introducing this console-only `_WindowsConsoleIO` class, which disrupts low-level patterns that people have relied on for decades.

---

<sup>1. `_WindowsConsoleIO` was added to support the full range of Unicode in the Windows console (at least as well as the console can support it). For this it uses the console's UTF-16 wide-character API (e.g. `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`). Previously CPython's console support was limited to text that was encoded with Windows codepages, using generic byte-based I/O (e.g. `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`).</sup>

<sup>2. Windows uses handles to reference kernel objects such as File objects. This system isn't compatible in behavior with POSIX file descriptors (FDs). The C runtime (CRT) thus has a "low I/O" compatibility layer that associates POSIX-style FDs with Windows file handles, and it also implements POSIX I/O functions such as `open` and `write`. The CRT's `_open_osfhandle` function associates a native file handle with an FD, and `_get_osfhandle` returns the handle associated with an FD. Sometimes CPython uses the CRT low I/O layer, and sometimes it uses the Windows API directly. It's really kind of a mess, if you ask me.</sup>